# Universal URL change event listener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I've been looking for some way (without using a timer) to detect when the URL changes in any way. Here is what I've found so far:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(){console.log('popstate changed')});
```

This code works just fine when the hash changes or a back/forward navigation is made. BUT, it doesn't catch when only the path changes. I tried it in the FireBase console where there is no hash in the URL and only the path changes when you navigate around. No dice, the popstate listener doesn't catch the change. Any advice?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate so if you managed, by changing the path, url whatever to trigger a change state you're OK. Even if the path changes (therefore you history navigate - the popstate should trigger...) I don't know about *FireBase console* but you could use the Developer Tools Console...

Comment: doesn't the page reload when the url path changes?

Comment: Nope, not always. There are ways to change the url without causing a reload...it's a sort of vanity url that lets you know where you're within the single page app @dandavis

Comment: so how do you change the path without navigating or calling pushState?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I'm not the one who changes the path, but I am the one trying to implement tracking on these types of single page apps :) @dandavis

Comment: you are probably best off tying into whatever causes the navigation. if that's not an available option, you _might_ be able to intercept link clicks and manually handle your events, it's worth a try. It's not 100% because the nav could be implemented in a way that's hard to intercept manually. you can build an interval timer checking `location.href` against the last-known value, and fire a custom pseudo-change event that way; draconian, but universally compatible.